# Represent MYSQL result with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

i need help for represent my query result into specific report with condition
[Here's my query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYAnF.png)
[image]
after get the result i need represent it as report with some condition, it would be like this:

[City A - Company A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1icp.png)

[image]

[City A - Company B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EJJX.png)

[image]

[City A - Company C - Service A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVK0N.png)

[image]

I've no idea how to do it since I'm really new to MySQL. 
I want to put the query into PHP.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please share the current table structure, sample data, the expected output, and your query attempts in readable form (as in: not as images)

Comment: Additionally, please don't use irrelevant tags. This question has no connection to phpMyAdmin, and also none to the concepts of a DateTime object

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

City A - Company A:

```
select pick_date, sum(Weight), 
sum(case when site = 'SiteA' then 1 else 0 end) as SiteA, 
sum(case when site = 'SiteB' then 1 else 0 end) as SiteB, 
sum(case when site = 'SiteC' then 1 else 0 end) as SiteC
From tbl
where company_name = 'CompanyA'
group by pick_date
```

For City A - Company B, replace 'CompanyA' with CompanyB in the query

For Company C - Service A:

```
select pick_date, sum(Weight), 
sum(case when site = 'SiteA' then 1 else 0 end) as SiteA, 
sum(case when site = 'SiteB' then 1 else 0 end) as SiteB, 
sum(case when site = 'SiteC' then 1 else 0 end) as SiteC
From tbl
where company_name = 'CompanyC' and service_name = 'ServiceA'
group by pick_date
```

Comment: Thanks, i continue to try build more dynamic condition ,  here's my code, but it doesn't show a result                                                                                                       
 SELECT  pickup_date,
 GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN site= ',site,' THEN ',weight,' ELSE 0 END) AS ', site))

FROM laundrytb_data WHERE company_name='CompanyA' AND 
service_name='ServiceA' AND 
pickup_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-03'
group by pickup_date

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. If your original query is also from SQL, put it into a temp table, and then using the following query will get you 3 answers.

```
SELECT
pickup_date
,SUM( CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteA]  
,SUM(CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteB]  
,SUM(CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteC]  

FROM
tbl

WHERE
[city] = 'CityA'
AND
[company_name] = 'CompanyA'

GROUP BY
pickup_date


SELECT
pickup_date
,SUM( CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteA]  
,SUM(CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteB]  
,SUM(CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteC]  

FROM
tbl

WHERE
[city] = 'CityA'
AND
[company_name] = 'CompanyB'

GROUP BY
pickup_date


SELECT
pickup_date
,SUM( CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteA]  
,SUM(CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteB]  
,SUM(CASE WHEN [site] = 'SiteB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [SiteC]  

FROM
tbl

WHERE
[city] = 'CityA'
AND
[company_name] = 'CompanyC'
AND
[service_name] = 'ServiceA'

GROUP BY
pickup_date
```